# How can I generate random numbers between -1 and 1 using rand_r

Tags: c, pthreads

I need help with how to generate random numbers between -1 and 1 using rand_r().  I didn't have much luck online looking for examples on how to do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly is your problem? This is not a tutorial website...

Comment: @Ludonope You're right, this is a Q&A site and in my opinion this question is valid for the site.

Comment: @cubrr: The question is too broad. Posters are required to show their re3search and why it does not work. Read [ask].

Comment: Indeed. You're supposed to produce the code that you're having problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `rand_r`, you pass it the address of a state variable.  Before calling `rand_r` the first time, this state variable should be assigned a seed value.  You'll also need to keep a separate state variable for each thread so they each have their own state.

```
unsigned int myseed = time(NULL) ^ getpid() ^ pthread_self();
...
int rand1 = rand_r(&myseed);
...
int rand2 = rand_r(&myseed);
```

To get a value between -1 and 1, first divide the given random value (cast to a `double`) by `RAND_MAX`.  This will give you a value between 0 and 1.  You then multiply by the range of the numbers (i.e. 1 - (-1) = 2) and add the lower bound (-1):

```
double rand = ((double)rand_r(&myseed) / RAND_MAX) * 2 - 1;
```

Comment: Why add the value from `getpid()` to `myseed`?

Comment: In general, better to use `time(NULL) ^ getpid();`  (^ vs. +) to mix random data.

Comment: @DavidBowling Use of `getpid(), myseed` prevents 2 calls if the program in the same second from generating the same result (or if `time()` fails)

Comment: @chux Agreed, should have thought of that.  Edited.

Comment: @dbush this worked but its generating the same random number for each thread.  How do i get it do generate a different random number for each thread?

Comment: @Ryan You need to keep track of a separate state variable for each thread, each with a different initial seed value.